# Quadruples of integers with $20^x + 14^{2y} = (x + 2y + z)^{zt}.$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Determine all quadruples $(x,y,z,t)$ of positive integers such that
$$20^x + 14^{2y} = (x + 2y + z)^{zt}.$$

We can check that $20+14^2=216=(1+2+3)^3$. But how can we check if there are other ones?

Comment: Where did you get the problem? What is it for?

Comment: @WillJagy It is from a European math competition. The competition is over, as you can check here: http://www.memo2014.de/index.php/competition/problems-2014. Thanks for asking :)